# Is there a good alternative GUIBuilder in java other than Netbeans? Alignment issue when using netbeans for Nimbus look and feel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, look-and-feel, nimbus

I am struggling with alignment issues when using Netbeans for designing UI in Nimbus look and feel. The preview is showing the alignment differently and I am having a really bad time trying to adjust the components.

Anybody else has this issue? What is the solution?

Are there any good alternatives for netbeans?

I never hand coded UI components. I have always used Netbeans as the applications I have to develop usually involves a lot of components and will get enhanced from time to time.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a hand-written [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: _I never hand coded UI components. I have always used Netbeans as the applications I have to develop usually involves a lot of components and will get enhanced from time to time._ Mores reason to hand-code the UI instead of relying on a GUI-builder which leads to hard to maintain stuff (until at some point, the code gets so un-understandable that you have to throw it all away).

Comment: @trashgod how to give code exmaple for an alignment issue?????

Comment: @afxgx: This frequently cited [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/230513) is illustrated for several L&Fs.